# Adding text to a field before save (Drupal 7)

Tags: entities, input-formats, uri, nodes

I run into a situation where I need to wrap text inputted into a field **before** it is saved. I'm not sure the best way to do this, seems pretty straightforward but I'd like to find the "recommended way", to pull this off.

I have a node type called Post.
There is a field that captures ID -> field_id 
Now I want to wrap this in HTML.

For example ->
(some html) . field_id . (/some more html)

Key point is that this append needs to happend before the save, rewritting the field in Views UI happens after the fact.

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7 ?

Answer (score 0):

you could create your own module and implement this hook:

[hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

This hook allows you to modify the node object (and corresponding fields) before it is saved or updated within the database.